# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django-angular'

Tags: django, django-angular

I have already installed

```
pip3 install django-angular
Requirement already satisfied: django-angular in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: django>=2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from django-angular) (3.2.12)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.3.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from django>=2.1->django-angular) (3.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from django>=2.1->django-angular) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from django>=2.1->django-angular) (2021.3)
```

but on running server it says

```
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django-angular'
```

I have already uninstalled & reinstalled it several times but no luck

Comment: Have you added django-angular to your installed_apps in settings.py?

Comment: Yup some of apps in settings.py 'crispy_forms',
    'django-angular',
    'django_comments_xtd',
    'django_comments',

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment for your project? Is django-angular installed on the correct environment?

Comment: Check the package documentation! https://django-angular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: yup, its was already installed but I changed the project folder & name. So, now when I reinstalled virtualenv env-name. The error disappeared for now. Thanks for now. Will run & get back if problem persists

Comment: Error again persists. I have reinstalled virtualenv, virtualenv env-name, activated env-name.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add `djng` to the list of `INSTALLED_APPS` in your project’s settings.py file

Further information can be found in the [docs](https://django-angular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

Comment: Already added but there's issue with npm install and the error is                            npm install angular --save
Sorry, name can only contain URL-friendly characters.

Comment: Same error with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django-polymorphic' . Force installed npm init -f & npm install angular --save

Comment: There's issue with pip3 which im using on Mac OS X Catalina 10.15.7